# MySQL is not opening from XAMPP and shows the following error

Tags: mysql, xampp

XAMPP shows the following errors in the log file when it attempts to start:

```
2017-04-26 11:19:09 af4 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
170426 11:19:09 [Note] InnoDB: Started in read only mode
170426 11:19:09 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
170426 11:19:09 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
170426 11:19:09 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
170426 11:19:09 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
170426 11:19:09 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
170426 11:19:09 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
170426 11:19:09 [Note] InnoDB: Disabling background IO write threads.
170426 11:19:09 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
170426 11:19:09 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
170426 11:19:09 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
170426 11:19:09 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 0 and 0 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 66856037668 in the ib_logfiles!
170426 11:19:09 [ERROR] InnoDB: Can't initiate database recovery, running in read-only-mode.
170426 11:19:09 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
170426 11:19:09 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
170426 11:19:09 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
170426 11:19:09 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
170426 11:19:09 [ERROR] Aborting

170426 11:19:09 [Note] d:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: It looks like you have a corruption on your database. What happened before you got this error, or what did you change just before this started happening

Comment: it was on running and suddently the sql server stopped .... and then it is not working

Comment: there is any  method to recover the  previous data... or yesterday data

Comment: Yes restore your last backup

Comment: dont have the backup how can we recover this issue with out backup..

Comment: As there is no simple answer to this [start by reading this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html) and also [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html)